# LI child element positioned to the side of LI parent

Tags: html, css

I have this structure:

```
<div style="position: relative" id="i1">
  <ul style="display: block" id="i2">
    <li style="display: inline-block; position: relative;" id="i3">
      <ul style="display: block;position: absolute; left: -??px; right: ??px" id="i4"> // visible on parent elm:hover
        <li>..</li>
        <li>..</li>
        <li>..</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I do need to show hovered element id=i4 always on the full width of DIV id=i1, but when my parent is element id=i3, and this element is relative inline, how i can reach the value of left and right attribute? can i do it clean by CSS?

Comment: An ID cannot start with a number. Try changing the ids to `id1` for starters. Regardless to your issue.

Comment: it is only for identification in this exaple, ok i will change it here

Comment: Can you create a snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, (my stupidity):

```
<div style="position: relative" id="i1"> /// only relative parent element
      <ul style="display: block" id="i2">
        <li style="display: inline-block; /*position: relative;*/" id="i3"> // removed position: relative;
          <ul style="display: block;position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px" id="i4"> // visible on parent elm:hover
            <li>..</li>
            <li>..</li>
            <li>..</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```